# is it possible to find sizeof and address of structure variables & globale variables during runtime?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

there are 4 .c/.h files. each having some global variables & structure variables. I got all the variables names from .map file . I extracted all in a two dimensional array/*array[](char type). now i want to pass sizeof each variables and address of it

Comment: would you mind a bit more clarification of your question?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: consider u have some . c/.h files. u have to pass as paremeter size of all variables and address of variables(global & structure). So i got a .map file which consider all the names of variables. i extracted variable names from this files store in buffer. it is poissible to any way by using buffer to pass addresses of variables and size of its

Comment: Do you need allocate the variables size with size content in .map file? I understand right? Your question is confuse.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. If you need allocate dynamic memory in a variable, you need use a malloc function in "stdlib.h" and to read the file, you can store this into a linked list to process one by one.

Check the example...
We have a 'variables.map' in this semantic:

```
eua 40
brasil 30
paris 15
horse 8
```

Where the first column is the name (maximum 40 chars **See struct prototype**) of variable and the second is the size. (Note: is separate by line break '\n')

The program load the file into a linked list in memory and allocate the respective memory spaces (Check main()).

See the example program...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//MAP prototype
typedef struct map {
    char name[40];
    unsigned int size;

    struct map *next;
} map;
//---

//Prototypes
void createList();
void insert(char[], int, map*);
void showList(map*);
unsigned int searchVariable(char[], map*);
void parseMapFile(char[]);
//---

//List, Linked list pointer
map *list_variables;
//---

//Main!
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    //Create list!
    createList();

    //Parse the .Map file into struct
    parseMapFile("/Users/gabriel/Documents/variables.map");

    //Show linked list
    //showList(list_variables);

    //------
    //Lets go now allocate the variables with the size in .map file

    //Allocate space!
    //Tipical types
    int   *eua    = malloc(searchVariable("eua", list_variables) * sizeof(int));
    char  *brasil = malloc(searchVariable("brasil", list_variables) * sizeof(char));
    float *paris  = malloc(searchVariable("paris", list_variables) * sizeof(float));

    //Alloc the void type (Undefined)
    void  *horse  = malloc(searchVariable("horse", list_variables) * sizeof(void));
    //---

    //Set values
    *eua = 5; //Integer
    strcpy(brasil, "Cool!"); //String
    *paris = 3.14; //Float
    *(int*)horse = (int) 7; //Set a integer value to void pointer!
    //---

    //Show up!
    printf("Variable eua: %d \n", *eua);
    printf("Variable brasil: %s \n", brasil);
    printf("Variable paris: %f \n", *paris);
    printf("Variable horse: %d \n", *((int*)horse));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


//Linked list functions...
//Allocate the linked list on memory
void createList() {
    list_variables = malloc( sizeof (map));
    list_variables->next = NULL;
}

//Insert the .MAP values into linked list
void insert(char name[], int size, map *p)
{
    map *new;

    new = malloc( sizeof (map));

    new->size = size;
    strcpy(new->name, name);
    new->next = p->next;
    p->next = new;
}

//Show variables loaded from .MAP file
void showList(map *list)
{
    map *p;
    for (p = list->next; p != NULL; p = p->next)
        printf("Variable: %s, Size: %d \n", p->name, p->size);
}

//Search variable in memory and return the size respective
unsigned int searchVariable(char name[], map *list)
{
    map *p;
    p = list->next;

    while (p != NULL && strcmp(name, p->name) != 0)
        p = p->next;

    return p->size;
}
//---

//Procedure to parse the map file in the specified structure!
void parseMapFile(char path[]) {
    char line[80];
    char name[40];
    unsigned int size;

    FILE *fp = fopen(path, "r");

    while(fgets(line, 80, fp) != NULL)
    {
        sscanf (line, "%s %d", name, &size);

        insert(name, size, list_variables);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

With this you really can allocate dynamic space with values stored in a file.

Comment: @GabrieBiga: hi, i have one more questions. My question is one file have all the global variables & structure variables . i read each variable at time. i want to pass address of that global variable/structure variable to a function. is it possible.if possible then how?